# Times not plotting correctly using sarima in R

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I ran into an issue while trying to use sarima.for which has led to the plot displaying incorrect times. As far as I can tell, the actual data is okay, just the dates.
Here's the short of what I put into the console:

```
SPX <- getSymbols("GSPC", auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2010-01-01")
SPXret <- SPX$GSPC.Close
SPXret <-as.ts(SPXret, start = c(2010, 1))
acf2(SPXret, max.lag = 12)
sarima(SPXret, 1, 1, 3)
```

I'm sure SPXret has the right time designations (begins at 2010 ends at present) and is an xts/zoo object. The issue is that when I use the function, the x axis starts at 3840 and ends at 3940! (As shown below)

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`SPX$GSPC.Close` is a daily series that starts on `2010-01-04`. 
 You need to specify this characteristic when defining the `SPXret` time-series object.

```
library(quantmod)
library(astsa)   

SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC", auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2010-01-01")
SPXret <- SPX$GSPC.Close
SPXret <- ts(SPXret, frequency=365, start=c(2010,4))
sarima.for(SPXret, 5, 1, 1, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh man I fixed the problem but forgot to mark the post as solved but thanks for the help! I think you'll find your solution a tad bit off due in part because you listed your frequency as 365 instead of 365.25, but the bigger issue is that securities data lacks weekends! The two factors explain the discrepancy between the 2015.3 (display forecasted to) and the most recent date of collection (august something 2017). For future reference for the forum, you'll have to either be okay with an odd time series, or fill in the weekends with NA values or scrapped data for off books trades.